# Vector calculaitons in R - troubles

Tags: r, vector

I have some troubles in calculations in R. I have a vector of few numbers, and one sequence of numbers (vector as well, i think). Now i need to power all numbers of first vector on first element of second vector, sum that numbers and go on with each element of the second vector. So my result would be a vector of the same number of elements as the second vector. But i dont know how to program this equation. This is just the first part of my calculations, but i thing i can solve the rest by myself.

Thanks for reply!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
x <- 1:5
y <- 1:3
res <- outer(x, y, "^")
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    1    1
# [2,]    2    4    8
# [3,]    3    9   27
# [4,]    4   16   64
# [5,]    5   25  125
colSums(res)
#[1]  15  55 225
```

Comment: Absolutelly perfect! Thx a lot!